# sending data from tab to another tab in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have 3 tab ( History , Upload, smth) in the "history" tab i have a listview that have data, i want from my "upload" tab where i have an edit text and a button, when i press the button i want the listview ,in my "history" tab , to be updated with what i wrote in the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

I use SharedPreferences.  Save it to SharedPreferences in the one tab, retrieve from SharedPreferences in the other.